# Bind event jquery when maxlength is hit

Tags: jquery

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" id="xpto" value="" maxlength="12" />
```

I want to trigger an event when `maxlength` is hit.

What I have now:

```
$("#xpto").keyup(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))) {
          //do stuff
      }
});
```

It's almost perfect, because it doesn't cover all possibilities (ie: User copying/paste values or select a browser's suggested value).

I was thinking on `$.bind()` but I haven't found any events that cover my scenario. Any help?

Comment: Use `$(document).on("keyup change", "#xpto", function(){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This do the trick:

```
$("#xpto")on('input', (function (e) {
   if ($(this).val().length == parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))) {
      //do stuff
   }
});
```

It covers copy/paste; typing; selecting suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `keyup event` to `change event` this will take care of coping and pasting and any other scenario.

`$("#xpto").change(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))) {
          //do stuff
      }
});`

Comment: actually `change event` it's just when you `change` fields, isn't? if I'm typing doesn't work until I get the `focus` out of the element

Comment: Change event is called whenever the field value changes. i.e any key stroke in the input field that modifies the value attribute